# different answers when using different loop constructs

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I had to create the following code to determine how much radiation one person was exposed to in certain amount of time. I created it with a `for` loop and my answer was 75% correct, I checked on a friend's code that used a `while` loop and, he had it 100% correct so, my question is Why or what is the difference between then both codes or what am I not doing in the `For` loop?

I called the function with these lines

```
radiationExposure(0, 11, 1)
radiationExposure(40, 100, 1.5)
```

and this is the code:

```
def f(x):
    import math
    return 10*math.e**(math.log(0.5)/5.27 * x)

def radiationExposure(start, stop, step):
    cuenta = 0.0
    Iter = stop - start

    for i in range(start,(Iter)+start):
        temp = f(i) * step
        cuenta += temp
    return cuenta
```

the other code (this is correct):

```
def f(x):
    import math
    return 10*math.e**(math.log(0.5)/5.27 * x)

def radiationExposure(start, stop, step):      
    result = 0
    while start < stop:
        result += f(start) * step
        start += step
    return result
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are ignoring the `step` parameter in your range. The `while` loop increments by adding `step` to `start`, but you increment by 1 only.

You could include the `step` value in your `for` loop:

```
for i in range(start, stop, step):
```

Note that I eliminated the `Iter` variable; you don't need it and it is redundant. Just use `stop` as the end value for the `range()` object.

Now `i` will be set to `start`, `start + 1 * step`, `start + 2 * step`, etc. rather than `start`, `start + 1`, `start + 2`, etc.

You probably did this because `range()` **doesn't support floating point values**. You cannot step with `1.5`, so to solve this question properly you **have** to use a different kind of loop.

You can still use `range()` if you really wanted to:

```
length = int(1 + (stop - 1 - start) / step)
for counter in range(length):
    i = start + counter * step
    temp = f(i) * step
    cuenta += temp
```

This calculates first how many steps in total your loop will have to perform, then loops that many times. Each iteration the actual value for that iteration is calculated from the loop counter.

I'd say using a `while` loop is easier.

At least with that change, the results of both approaches is the same:

```
>>> import math
>>> def f(x):
...     return 10*math.e**(math.log(0.5)/5.27 * x)
... 
>>> def radiationExposure_while(start, stop, step):
...     result = 0
...     while start < stop:
...         result += f(start) * step
...         start += step
...     return result
... 
>>> def radiationExposure_range(start, stop, step):
...     result = 0
...     length = int(1 + (stop - 1 - start) / step)
...     for counter in range(length):
...         i = start + counter * step
...         result += f(i) * step
...     return result
... 
>>> radiationExposure_range(0, 11, 1) == radiationExposure_while(0, 11, 1)
True
>>> radiationExposure_range(40, 100, 1.5) == radiationExposure_while(40, 100, 1.5)
True
```

Comment: As a random trivia question, any idea why `range` doesn't support `float` values for `step`? Seems like it would be super trivial to account for.

Comment: @Cyber: because `float` arithmetic isn't so simple? It may be for the `1.5` step size case, but what about **really tiny** step sizes? Or using `float('inf')` as a start or stop value, etc.? When using float, you need to deal with more corner cases that require explicit handling.

Comment: That's true I guess, always have to protect against bad inputs. Seems like a pain in the butt.

Comment: I did not used step in the range() does not support floating ... but if I do it the way you give me in the example it goes very far from the answer, please try with this test cases:

    radiationExposure(0, 5, 1) >>>39.10318784326239

    radiationExposure(5, 11, 1) >>>22.94241041057671

    radiationExposure(40, 100, 1.5)>>>0.434612356115

Comment: @EstebanG.Gutierrez: I just did and the outcome for the `while` vs. the `for .. in range` approach I gave in my answer is exactly the same for those inputs.

Comment: try this test case:

 radiationExposure(40, 100, 1.5)>>>0.434612356115

Comment: @EstebanG.Gutierrez: why are those outcomes surprising? You first calculated the sum of `f(0) + f(1) + f(2) + f(3) + f(4)` then calculated `f(5) + f(6) + f(7) + f(8) + f(9) + f(10)`.

Comment: @EstebanG.Gutierrez: I showed you in my answer that the result for `radiationExposure(40, 100, 1.5)` is *exactly the same* when using my `range()` approach vs. the `while` loop.

Comment: @EstebanG.Gutierrez: `radiationExposure_range(40, 100, 1.5)` produces 
`0.4346123561149849`, yes. But so does `radiationExposure_while(40, 100, 1.5)`. Did you expect a different outcome?

Comment: Because in the firs year(0) you are more exposed to radiation, so if you live in one placed that is 5 years older then you need to calculate the radiation from the 5th year to the last year you lived in there ... so what you do is to multiply the result from def F(x) times the current year exposure (it is diferrent every year) and then you add them up to get the total exposure of certain period of time.

Comment: @EstebanG.Gutierrez: You stated that the `while` function produced the correct results. Are you saying that it doesn't produce the correct results now?

Comment: Well then I must still not understand something., because I could not get it to work properly, let me try and this is the problem if you would like to read more about it . Thank you for your help.  http://blog.leanote.com/post/54c79ec7cf50f42190000001

my answer is still wrong after changing my code to your suggestion 

radiationExposure(40, 100, 1.5)
Out[169]: 121.07776889004202

Comment: The while loop is ok but I did not create that code, so my code is still wrong my code will not work with floats in the step argument.

Comment: @EstebanG.Gutierrez: are you using my `length = ...` and `for count in range(length)` loop at all?

Comment: @EstebanG.Gutierrez: also, are you certain for `f()` function is correct? I see that it is supplied by the tester, so it could differ from test case to test case, but that shouldn't matter here.

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters  You Are completely correct I just double checked and I had mistype the code ... You were correct all this time, Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop steps by `1` and ignores the `step` parameter

```
for i in range(start, (Iter)+start)
```

To account for the step, add the last parameter to `range`

```
for i in range(start, (Iter)+start, step)
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters You are right, I was double-confused